# how to join 2 queries into 1

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, cpu-usage

I am trying to join 2 of the following queries

```
select * from MapCountries where IndexName='SPX Index' and date(ModifiedDate)='2015-04-24';

select DRegion,DCountry,GICS1,GICS2,LRY,BBGLableValues from CompanyDetails where IndexName='SPX Index' and CompanyTicker='A UN' and date(ModifiedDate)='2015-04-24';
```

the second query is fired from the "while(reader.read())" of the first query.
This is taking up a lot of CPU time. SO is there a way to join these 2 queries to reduce the CPU usage?

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    var regionModelTest = new RegionModelTest();
    ExtractCompanyDetails(Index, regionModelTest);
    ...
}

ExtractCompanyDetails(Index, regionModelTest)
{
   second query;
}
```

the CompanyTicker for the 2nd query comes from one of the fields of the first query.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Can you show us the relevant information of the tables, please? How are they linked together?

Comment: Read about WITH operator. You can make first table result as a TEMP TABLE and later use it in second select.

Comment: You have IndexName column in both tables. So, you can create a query with joining both tables. Anyway, if you want us to write the query for you, you need to provide both table structure and logic.

Comment: Thanks guys.. @MajkeloDev is it really necessary to create a TEMP table to reduce CPU usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a simple left join:

```
select * from MapCountries mc
left join CompanyDetails cd on mc.IndexName = cd.IndexName and mc.ModifiedDate = cd.ModifiedDate
where mc.IndexName='SPX Index' and date(mc.ModifiedDate)='2015-04-24' and cd.CompanyTicker='A UN'
```

Comment: worked flawlessly... thanks a ton.. hopefully it will help reduce my CPU usage